# Find the secret used to encrypt a file if the result is known

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, md5, hmac

I have a file, I know the result of computing its HMAC-MD5, is there a way to find the secret used for HMAC-MD5 computation?

I can calculate the HMAC-MD5 using OpenSSL, is there a way to find the secret using OpenSSL as well?:

```
cat file.bin | openssl dgst -md5 -hmac '<secret>')
<Known output>
```

Comment: Yes, just try all possibilities for the secret until you find the correct one. This is a *brute force* approach that may be computationally impractical depending on what is known about the set of values the secret is a member of.

Comment: There are currently no known attacks on HMAC-MD5, so no. (If you could do what you're describing, that would be massive failure of the algorithm) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9336/is-hmac-md5-considered-secure-for-authenticating-encrypted-data  For information on brute-forcing HMAC, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6750/brute-forcing-an-hmac/6753 (In general, these questions belong on crypto.stackexchange.com)